# Terraform NAT Gateway forcing new resource every apply

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Thanks for your help in advance.(new to terraform)

Terraform is creating a new NAT gateway everytime during terraform apply. I am obviously missing something here,

```
resource "aws_eip" "tfeip"{
  vpc      = true
  depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.igw"]
  tags{
    Name = "${var.vpc_env}-tf-eip-nat-gw"
  }
}

# Create NAT Gateway
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat-gw" {
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.tfeip.id}"
  subnet_id  = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.public-subnets.ids, 0)}"
  depends_on = ["aws_internet_gateway.igw"]
  tags{
    Name = "${var.vpc_env}-tf-nat-gateway"
  }
}
```

Terraform creates the new allocation ID and inturn the NAT gateway gets created everytime. Any idea what i am missing?

Here's the my plan output,

````
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

aws_nat_gateway.nat-gw: Refreshing state...
data.aws_eip.eipid: Refreshing state...
aws_vpc.tfvpc: Refreshing state... [id=vpc-02f8c59a8497b4106]
aws_subnet.tfprivate[1]: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-08e2c6d4747f6825b]
aws_internet_gateway.igw: Refreshing state... [id=igw-0a2e4bac38e4daf38]
aws_subnet.tfprivate[0]: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-0b1e4b8c079eba45a]
aws_network_acl.tf-private-acl: Refreshing state... [id=acl-0c7e5678f7cc69c21]
aws_subnet.tfpublic[0]: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-055b2b384d0c0ce66]
aws_subnet.tfpublic[1]: Refreshing state... [id=subnet-048769cf43c37022b]
aws_eip.tfeip: Refreshing state... [id=eipalloc-0e5020f276b019d1a]
aws_route_table.tf-public-route: Refreshing state... [id=rtb-0c036c023e7949d24]
aws_nat_gateway.nat-gw: Refreshing state... [id=nat-0df993ed23f40559f]
aws_route_table_association.tf-public-route-association[0]: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-0dbfff44cb44ef6e6]
aws_route_table_association.tf-public-route-association[1]: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-05b2e9420129b6cad]
aws_route_table.tf-private-route: Refreshing state... [id=rtb-00d7850a8294282b5]
aws_route_table_association.tf-private-route-association[0]: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-06d65de0b71461ac4]
aws_route_table_association.tf-private-route-association[1]: Refreshing state... [id=rtbassoc-04658d796d38247d7]
aws_vpc_endpoint.s3-vpce: Refreshing state... [id=vpce-0c48db5bd18368299]

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place
-/+ destroy and then create replacement
 <= read (data resources)

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # data.aws_subnet_ids.private-subnets will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "aws_subnet_ids" "private-subnets"  {
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + ids    = (known after apply)
      + tags   = {
          + "Type" = "Private"
        }
      + vpc_id = "vpc-02f8c59a8497b4106"
    }

  # data.aws_subnet_ids.public-subnets will be read during apply
  # (config refers to values not yet known)
 <= data "aws_subnet_ids" "public-subnets"  {
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + ids    = (known after apply)
      + tags   = {
          + "Type" = "Public"
        }
      + vpc_id = "vpc-02f8c59a8497b4106"
    }

  # aws_nat_gateway.nat-gw must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat-gw" {
        allocation_id        = "eipalloc-0e5020f276b019d1a"
      ~ id                   = "nat-0df993ed23f40559f" -> (known after apply)
      ~ network_interface_id = "eni-09a821bxxxxx39297" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip           = "10.38.0.21" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip            = "3.225.5.235" -> (known after apply)
      ~ subnet_id            = "subnet-055b2b384d0c0ce66" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
        tags                 = {
            "Name" = "dev-tf-nat-gateway"
        }
    }

  # aws_route_table.tf-private-route will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_route_table" "tf-private-route" {
        id               = "rtb-00d7850a8294282b5"
        owner_id         = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        propagating_vgws = []
      ~ route            = [
          - {
              - cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
              - egress_only_gateway_id    = ""
              - gateway_id                = ""
              - instance_id               = ""
              - ipv6_cidr_block           = ""
              - nat_gateway_id            = "nat-0df993ed23f40559f"
              - network_interface_id      = ""
              - transit_gateway_id        = ""
              - vpc_peering_connection_id = ""
            },
            {
                cidr_block                = "0.0.0.0/0"
                egress_only_gateway_id    = ""
                gateway_id                = ""
                instance_id               = ""
                ipv6_cidr_block           = ""
                nat_gateway_id            = (known after apply)
                network_interface_id      = ""
                transit_gateway_id        = ""
                vpc_peering_connection_id = ""
            },
        ]
        tags             = {
            "Name" = "dev-tf-private-rt-table"
        }
        vpc_id           = "vpc-02f8c59a8497b4106"
    }

  # aws_route_table_association.tf-private-route-association[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_route_table_association" "tf-private-route-association" {
      ~ id             = "rtbassoc-06d65de0b71461ac4" -> (known after apply)
        route_table_id = "rtb-00d7850a8294282b5"
      ~ subnet_id      = "subnet-08e2c6d4747f6825b" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }

  # aws_route_table_association.tf-private-route-association[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_route_table_association" "tf-private-route-association" {
      ~ id             = "rtbassoc-04658d796d38247d7" -> (known after apply)
        route_table_id = "rtb-00d7850a8294282b5"
      ~ subnet_id      = "subnet-0b1e4b8c079eba45a" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }

  # aws_route_table_association.tf-public-route-association[0] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_route_table_association" "tf-public-route-association" {
      ~ id             = "rtbassoc-0dbfff44cb44ef6e6" -> (known after apply)
        route_table_id = "rtb-0c036c023e7949d24"
      ~ subnet_id      = "subnet-048769cf43c37022b" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }

  # aws_route_table_association.tf-public-route-association[1] must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_route_table_association" "tf-public-route-association" {
      ~ id             = "rtbassoc-05b2e9420129b6cad" -> (known after apply)
        route_table_id = "rtb-0c036c023e7949d24"
      ~ subnet_id      = "subnet-055b2b384d0c0ce66" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
    }

Plan: 5 to add, 1 to change, 5 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.```
````

Comment: Can you show the plan output when it wants to recreate the NAT gateway?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR please find the below plan output attached in the question section

Comment: It looks like it thinks the subnet ID has changed for where you want the NAT gateway. Are you saying that if you `apply` and then `plan` again it wants to recreate the next time as well and shows a different subnet ID for the NAT?

Comment: Your plan output also includes some data resources like `data "aws_subnet_ids" "private-subnets"`, which Terraform says must be refreshed during the apply step rather than the plan step, and I expect that's the root cause here. Could you share the configuration for those `data` blocks as part of your question too?

Answer (score 0):

@ydaetskcoR The issue is resolved after creating one gateway per AZ on all the public subnets and removing the old orphan gateway from the state file.